# Windows ping to Any IP including 127.0.0.1 hangs, but internet works

Tags: windows, networking, ping, traceroute, icmp

I have weird behavior on my Windows 10 operating system. Any ping/tracert command hangs and nothing happens. I have never seen something like this before, and all i have found in the google aren't my situations.

**What i was doing:**

I'm developer and was testing VPN application, it's do connect to backend server over "WAN Miniport (IKEv2)" interface and control the connection. I had the bug and for while testing i did a lot of reconnections/connection stops and at the end of day i got this issue.

The Day before i had no problems with this...

**How the problems looks:**

When i type "**ping** ANYHOST/ANYIP/127.0.0.1" the ping utility hangs and nothing happens:

[image]

Same for **tracert** command, 0 hops. I was waiting over 1 hour and nothing changed.

I downloaded Ping software, and they also do nothing (doesnt work), if i do C# Ping.SendPing() it hangs too.

My Envirement:

- Windows 10
- Windows Firewall service off
- No active firewall softwares
- No weird errors in the Windows Errors Log

Route print result here:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    291
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    291
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

If you have some ideas what to test feel free to ask. Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is my **ipconfig** configuration. I have a lot of network adapters but they are diconnected.

```
C:\Users\sap>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SAP
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-07-BE-AB-1A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter !Main ethernet adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 70-85-C2-FA-CC-A8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 359695810
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-24-F2-D0-6B-50-46-5D-59-78-73
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Could be something is doing s.th. with your ICMP traffic (yes, I know your FW is off, still...), what does ipconfig /all tell you?

Comment: Is this problem ICMP specific or does it concern other protocols as well?

Comment: It sounds like your TCP/IP stack is corrupted. Try resetting it and see what happens

Comment: @Tim_Stewart that's what I thought as well, but since other protocols seem to work isn't this unlikely?

Comment: @albin, I don't see that indicated by the op. **"One more weird behavier is DHCP, my router gives me correct DNS, but IP somehow is 4 random numbers"** ~ this needs more detail/explanation it sounds like he may have a apipa IP address on the adapter.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Yeah, I meant "but internet works"

Comment: @Albin Hey there! I have added ipconfig, but it looks typical. Thanks

Comment: @Albin well, everything works well, i can connect to anywhere and do what i want expect ping command, thats real weird

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Hey there, how to reset that? They problem keeps after reboot, how to do that? Thanks

Comment: BTW, i dont know why, but DHCP works well now, i have got correct settings. (Removed this issure from post)

Comment: Internet works well, all applications hasnt any problems to works with network.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Thanks you very much, IP reset has solved my issure, post your answer and i willl mark it as ansewer. Reset command is "netsh int ip reset"

Comment: Glad I could help. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I had this happen to me when I was working on a VPN client problem in windows 8.1. The vpn app crashed while doing a transfer, also IKEv2. pings failed, with strange DHCP behavior.

For anyone else experiencing something like this:

The key indicator is that you can no longer ping the loopback address **127.0.0.1**, this means the **TCP/IP** stack in the operating system is no longer functioning correctly.

This should work in **WIN7/8.1/10**:

To Reset the TCP/IP Stack in Windows.

1. Click the Start button in the bottom left corner of the screen.
2. Type Command Prompt in the Search bar. Then right-click on the Command Prompt icon, and select Run as administrator.
3. If prompted, select Yes to allow changes to be made to computer.
4. Type in **netsh int ip reset**, and press Enter.

These TCP/IP reset instructions are from:
https://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=19483

And they are apparently referenced from: Microsoft.com